# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page that gets value from SQL. I'm having a problem when I initialize Label object with the field having TEXT data type.

Below is my code.

```
Dim csq As New Survey.DAL.CSurvey
csq.SurveyID = ViewState("SurveyId")
Dim dt As DataTable = csq.GetSurveyThankYouDetails
For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
    lblThankYoutext.text = r.Item("QuestionText") ' error falls here
    lbtLink.Text = r.Item("ThankYouLinkText")
Next
```

Comment: Whats the error? Are you talking about the SQL Text data type?

Comment: Do you still get the error even though you changed the line to `lblThankYoutext.text = r.Item("QuestionText")`?

Answer (score 4):

`lblThankYou.Text` perhaps (as opposed to `lblThankYoutext`)

Answer (score 2):

```
lblThankYoutext.Text = r.Item("QuestionText")
```

Answer (score 2):

`lblThankYoutext` is a web control, use the `.Text` property of the label to assign it a value.

`lblThankYoutext.Text = r.Item("QuestionText")`

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
labelName.text =Convert.ToString( r.Item("QuestionText"))
```